# Видео чат. что нужно?

Tags: видео, online-video

Есть идея сделать видео чат в вебе. То бишь два юзера находясь на разных веб страницах общаются через видео трансляцию друг с другом (типо как на twitch и подобных сервисах)

Что для этого нужно?

Имею: Java EE веб сервер и два клиента с поддержкой JavaScript.

Comment: Нужно сущие пустяки :) вебсервер должен уметь гонять видео потоки в формате в котором понимает плеер который вы выбирете для реализации. Если хочется чтоб клиенты слали видео на прямую, то надо их как то синхронизировать с состоянием сервера, хотя если делать что то типа коннект-прокси, то будет проще. Вообще задача мало подъёмная, требует адаптации/написания соответствующего софта. Может просто кнопку приделать? от Скайпа например :)

Comment: С таким уровнем знаний, это Вам рановато. Изучите хотя бы вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC

Comment: @Tsyklop, бросьте вы эту затею, на 2 юзера это не серьёзно :) Или возьмите Астерикс, соберите под него кодеков нужных, создайте диал планы, и используйте как готовый SIP сервис.

Comment: @NewView, а мне кажется, задача не сильно сложная. Воспроизведение - html5 video. Трансляция - ещё в 2013 году [было на хабре](https://habr.com/post/172419/), ну и нужен https и сервер, проксирующий трафик. Если о большой нагрузке речи не идёт, всё должно быть вполне осуществимо.

Comment: @Tsyklop Если решите копать в сторону WebRTC, то вот [интересный репозиторий](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/demos/One-to-One.html)

Comment: @Qwertiy, посмотрел статью :) - творческий подход, однозначно. Но  решения типа 'использовать base64 сжатие всего, что находится на canvas' больно уж велосипедные, на мой взгляд, для этого есть уже придуманные протоколы, как мне кажеться.

Comment: @NewView, ну да, должно быть что-то. К тому же, уже 5 лет прошло с написания статьи - по-любому есть что-то в стандарте для отправки видеопотока на сервер - без этого это была бы весьма сомнительная фича. Но в целом должно получаться относительно несложно и для двух человек общаться вполне подойдёт.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78588/discussion-on-question-by-tsyklop----).

Comment: WebRTC вам в помощь. Спокойно можно реализовать, как мультипользовательские чаты, так и приватные.